# bit shift different result in similar programs

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Here is one program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned char a=0x80;
 printf("%d\n",a<<1);
}
```

The output of above is `256`
Now here is one more version of above program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned char a=0x80;
  a=a<<1;
 printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

The output of above is

```
0
```

As far as my understanding is I am not able to see any difference between the two?
i.e. why is output coming 256 in first one and 0 in second program what is the difference in statements in both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `a << 1` is of type `int` according to the C language's type-promotion rules. In the first program, you are taking this `int`, which now has the value `0x100`, and passing it directly to `printf()`, which works as expected.

In the second program, your `int` is assigned to an `unsigned char`, which results in truncation of `0x100` to `0x00`.

Answer (score 10):

On your platform, `unsigned char` is only 8 bits wide, so `a << 1` shifts the 1 out the left end when you assign it back to the narrow `a`. In the `printf` call, on the other hand, `a` is first promoted to an integer (which is wider than 8 bits on your platform) and thus the bit survives.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` promotes the result to an (unsigned) `int`, but in the second example, you force it back into an (unsigned) `char` where it overflows back to 0.

Comment: `a=a<<1;` I think I force it back to (unsigned char) correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: but you said it force back to an (unsigned) int that is my confusion.

Comment: Oh oopsies! Ran out of coffee again... But yes, you are correct, you're doing a narrowing cast and losing the higher order bits, leaving you with zero.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, `a` is only 8 bit long, `0x80 << 1` is `0x100` then cast to a char clips the top bit so becomes `0x00`

When directly in the `printf` statement, it is looking for an `int` so it won't clip it...